# Mobile remote data loading: lazy vs eager

Tags: rest, mobile, lazy-loading

I am developing several mobile apps.  These apps are complex with many hierarchies of data.

What is the optimal way to load remote data?  Should I load a comprehensive set of the data from the top of the hierarchy all the way down? This would cause the app to take a long time to load for the first time, but be much faster throughout the rest of the app session because the data is cached after that.

Should I lazy load the remote data to only load what I need when a user clicks on a row or component? This would cause the app load slower on each click but would cut down on the initial load of much data.

Comment: You can also use a combination of the two approaches, loading just a level or two down from the current position in the hierarchy.

Comment: Seems to me the main criterion isn't whether the app is mobile...but whether you're likely to need all that data right away.  People are willing to wait a second or so per click if it doesn't mean waiting 30 seconds to log in.  In fact, i've actually had to *add* a delay to an app cause people weren't convinced it was really doing its job til it acted like it was doing some heavy-duty processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've see both.  My latest attempt, yoga, at the problem was to create a more flexible server-side that allows a single URL return the exact information that a screen would need.  It was a take off of something that LinkedIn did a while back.  Right now, it's purely a Java solution, but the basics can be transferred to other platforms: https://github.com/skyscreamer/yoga